# Using CSS Variables for position offset

Tags: css, variables

I've reading about native CSS variables for declaring colors, but I wondering if there is a way to create a variable for top: left positions? I have a CSS template that overlays text boxes on an image, and the layout page get's changed periodically by the designer.  I'd like to accomplish something like this:

```
    :root {
      --topOffset: 10px;
      -- leftOffset: 20px;
    }
    
.text_Date_Overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 516px + topOffset;
    left:570px + leftOffset;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:18px;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

Is there a way, other than going into JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them with `calc()` and do something like this.

```
:root {
  --topOffset: 10px;
  --leftOffset: 20px;
}

.text_Date_Overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(516px + var(--topOffset));
  left: calc(570px + var(--leftOffset));
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:18px;
  font-style:italic;
}
```

[View Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thelessergeek/syfkg0to/)